# Passing a global value as argument to a decorator and the function

Tags: python, arguments, global, decorator

I am new to python and learning decorators. Decorators with NO arguments and WITH arguments(as string) seems to be straight forward. But however if i want to pass a global value instead of a 'srting' as arguments it fails. I have all this is different files, so i want to use global variable.

```
File1:
def decorator(arg1, arg2):
    def real_decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args):
            print "i am decorated"
            print arg1, arg2
            function(*args)
        return wrapper
    return real_decorator

File2:
def glob(a, b):
    global arg1
    arg1 = a
    global arg2
    arg2 = b

@decorator(arg1, arg2) # pass it as 'string' ie('arg1', 'arg2') it PASSES, pass it as i have showed, it FAILS
def print_args(*args):
    print 'i am ordinary'
    for arg in args:
        print arg

File3:
#calling functions
glob(1, 2)
print_args(3,4,5)
======================================
Pass: (when given as string)
i am decorated
arg1 arg2
i am ordinary
3
4
5
======================================
Fail: (when given global var)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/User/File2.py", line 19, in <module>
@decorator(arg1, arg2)
NameError: global name 'arg1' is not defined
```

Any help with this much appreciated. I am stuck with this since yesterday..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare `arg1` and `arg2` at the zero-indentation level, i.e., as a global variable inside your module:

```
arg1 = None
arg2 = None

def decorator(arg1, arg2):
    def real_decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args):
            print("i am decorated")
            print(arg1, arg2)
            function(*args)
        return wrapper
    return real_decorator

def glob(a, b):
    global arg1
    arg1 = a
    global arg2
    arg2 = b

glob(1, 2)

#calling functions
@decorator(arg1, arg2) # pass it as 'string' ie('arg1', 'arg2') it PASSES, pass it as i have showed, it FAILS
def print_args(*args):
    print('i am ordinary')
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)


print_args(3,4,5)
```

In addition, make sure to call `glob(1, 2)` before passing `arg1`, and `arg2` as parameters of your decorator.

Comment: But i am sending arg1 and arg2 from @decorator(arg1, arg2). I do not want to initialize the value again.. Am i missing something.?

Comment: @h_vm, yes, the missing is that they are not defined in the global scope, so `@decorator(arg1, arg2)` is exactly the line where you are getting the error since these variables are not declared.

Comment: It is printing 'None' only for arg1 and arg2 when i define the global var as (arg1 = None and arg2 = None).

Comment: @h_vm, what do you mean by this?

Comment: Its printing: i am decorated \n
None None \n
1 2 \n
i am ordinary \n
3 \n
4 \n
5 \n

Comment: @h_vm, and what is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry it is printing: i am decorated \n None None \n i am ordinary \n 3 \n 4 \n 5 \n..... expected: instead of None None it should be 1 2

Comment: @h_vm, I have updated my answer, I think this time it solves your problem